# SignalR hub proxy in Angular not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr

I'm attempting to add SignalR to my Angular MVC app.  I've used [this](http://henriquat.re/server-integration/signalr/integrateWithSignalRHubs.html) article as a starting point which has a hub proxy factory which it uses to... well... proxy hub calls. I have it all setup, but my hub on the server is not able to communicate with my Angular code.  Here is my code:

Hub proxy factory:

```
app.factory('hubProxy', ['$rootScope', 'signalRUrl', function ($rootScope, signalRUrl) {

    function hubFactory(hubName) {
        var connection = $.hubConnection(signalRUrl);
        var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);

        connection.start().done(function () { });

        return {
            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                proxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            invoke: function (methodName, callback) {
                proxy.invoke(methodName)
                .done(function (result) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            connection: connection
        };
    };

    return hubFactory;
}]);
```

Angular controller:

```
angular.module('testApp').controller('testController', ['$scope', 'hubProxy', function ($scope, hubProxy) {
    var pendingPaymentsHub = hubProxy('pendingPaymentsHub');

    pendingPaymentsHub.on('onUpdatePendingPayment', function (data) {
        console.log('hub callback!');
    });
}]);
```

Hub:

```
[HubName("pendingPaymentsHub")]
public class PendingPaymentsHub : Hub
{
    private static IHubContext hub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PendingPaymentsHub>();

    public static void UpdatePendingPayment(PendingPaymentViewModel pendingPayment)
    {
        hub.Clients.All.onUpdatePendingPayment(pendingPayment);
    }
}
```

My hub is called from an API controller, in this case, after an update is complete.  It is called like this:

```
PendingPaymentsHub.UpdatePendingPayment(pendingPayment);
```

When the page loads, both the `/signalr/negotiate` and `/signalr/start` calls are successfully run (confirmed in browser dev tool by 200s).  I can also confirm that the `UpdatePendingPayment` method in my hub is hit by debugging.  I simply get nothing on the front-end.  Why?

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**
To be clear, the issue is with the hub proxy factory.  When I replace the factory implementation with the following in my controller, everything works as expected:

```
function initializeHub() {
    connection = $.hubConnection(signalRUrl);
    hub = connection.createHubProxy('pendingPaymentsHub');

    hub.on('onUpdatePendingPayment', function (data) {
        console.log('success');
    });

    connection.start();
};
```

Comment: I happened to have used the exact same proxy factory once. Nothing odd I can see. Is this maybe just a scope issue in your controller? `var pendingPaymentsHub` vs `this.pendingPaymentsHub`

Comment: @rdoubleui Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: Strange, hope somebody else has an idea. Want to know the cause!

Answer (score 0):

Try upper case for the server side method call of the client even though it starts lowercase on the client side:

```
hub.Clients.All.OnUpdatePendingPayment(pendingPayment);
```

Check the generated proxy to see what method mapping is done, this is where I found out about the upper case issue.

The point [Misspelled method, incorrect method signature, or incorrect hub name](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting) covers this, the proxy uses camelCase:

> [...] Also, SignalR creates the hub proxy using camel-cased methods, as
>   is appropriate in JavaScript, so a method called SendMessage on the
>   server would be called sendMessage in the client proxy.

Comment: Depending on the version used this might not be an issue anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It didn't work.  I'm using 2.2.0.  See my update.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working from the exact same tutorial, I believe the issue is that you have to call connection.start() -after- you define the .on() method for the hubProxy object. I've no idea how the tutorial example is supposed to work in that case though.

Here's my redone service:

```
app.factory('hubProxy', ['$rootScope', 'serverUrl', function ($rootScope, serverUrl) {

    function backendFactory(hubName) {
        $.support.cors = true;
        var connection = $.hubConnection(serverUrl);
        var proxy = connection.createHubProxy(hubName);

        return {

            on: function (eventName, callback) {
                proxy.on(eventName, function (result) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            invoke: function (methodName, callback) {
                proxy.invoke(methodName)
                .done(function (result) {
                    $rootScope.$apply(function () {
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
            start: function(){
                connection.start().done(function () { });
            }
        };
    };

    return backendFactory;
}]);
```

then you just have to call start() after you call the on() method:

```
app.controller('hubDataController', ['$scope', 'hubProxy',
    function ($scope, hubProxy) {

    var proxy = hubProxy('remoteHub');        

    proxy.on('broadcast', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    proxy.start();
}
```

]);